# Couldn't able to run "qt-windows-static-build.ps1" properly

Tags: qt, qt6

I'm trying to make a standalone executable for my QT Console application. So i figured out [Building a static Qt for Windows using MinGW](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW) and followed step by step instructions.
When i ran the script, it gave me errors for downloading qt-everywhere-src.ps1 so I manually download the [archive](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.2/6.2.3/single/qt-everywhere-src-6.2.3.zip) and placed it in the appropriate location i.e. C:\Qt\Static\src as per the script.

Then I ran the script and it gave me the below output

```
Building static Qt version 6.2.3
Using MinGW from C:\Qt\Tools\mingw900_64
+ cd qtbase
+ C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-src-6.2.3\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -static -release -platform win32-g++ -opensource -confirm-license -prefix C:\Qt\Static\6.2.3 -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-webp -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype  -no-opengl -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtcharts -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip qtlocation -skip qtlottie -skip qtmacextras -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtpurchasing -skip qtquick3d -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtquicktimeline -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtscript -skip qtsensors -skip qtspeech -skip qtsvg -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebglplugin -skip qtwebview -skip webengine -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
-- Windows 10 SDK version:
opt: zlib val: qt
opt: libpng val: qt
Overriding option 'libpng' with 'qt' (was: 'undefined')
opt: webp val: qt
Overriding option 'webp' with 'qt' (was: 'undefined')
opt: libjpeg val: qt
Overriding option 'libjpeg' with 'qt' (was: 'undefined')
opt: freetype val: qt
Overriding option 'freetype' with 'qt' (was: 'undefined')
CMake Warning at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:247 (message):
  '-nomake tools' is not implemented yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:782 (qtConfAddWarning)
  qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:842 (check_qt_build_parts)


CMake Warning at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:247 (message):
  '-make libs' is not implemented yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:782 (qtConfAddWarning)
  qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:843 (check_qt_build_parts)


'C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe' '-DBUILD_qt3d=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtactiveqt=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtandroidextras=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtcharts=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtconnectivity=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtdatavis3d=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtdeclarative=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtdoc=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtgamepad=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtlocation=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtlottie=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtmacextras=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtmultimedia=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtnetworkauth=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtpurchasing=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtquick3d=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtquickcontrols=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtquickcontrols2=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtquicktimeline=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtremoteobjects=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtscript=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtsensors=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtspeech=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtsvg=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtwayland=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtwebglplugin=OFF' '-DBUILD_qtwebview=OFF' '-DBUILD_webengine=OFF' '-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF' '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C://Qt//Static//6.2.3' '-DQT_QMAKE_TARGET_MKSPEC=win32-g++' '-DQT_BUILD_EXAMPLES=FALSE' '-DQT_BUILD_TESTS=FALSE' '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' '-DINPUT_system_zlib=no' '-DINPUT_libpng=qt' '-DINPUT_webp=qt' '-DINPUT_libjpeg=qt' '-DINPUT_freetype=qt' '-DINPUT_opengl=no' '-G' 'MinGW Makefiles' 'C:/Qt/Static/src/qt-everywhere-src-6.2.3'
CMake Warning at qtbase/cmake/QtAutoDetect.cmake:65 (message):
  The officially supported CMake generator for building Qt is Ninja.  You are
  using: 'MinGW Makefiles' instead.  Thus, you might encounter issues.  Use
  at your own risk.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtAutoDetect.cmake:439 (qt_auto_detect_cmake_generator)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (include)


Checking dependencies of 'qtbase'
Checking dependencies of 'qtshadertools'
Checking dependencies of 'qtimageformats'
Checking dependencies of 'qtcoap'
Checking dependencies of 'qttools'
Skipping optional dependency 'qtactiveqt' of 'qttools', because building 'qtactiveqt' was explicitly disabled.
Skipping optional dependency 'qtdeclarative' of 'qttools', because building 'qtdeclarative' was explicitly disabled.
Checking dependencies of 'qtserialport'
Checking dependencies of 'qtpositioning'
Skipping optional dependency 'qtdeclarative' of 'qtpositioning', because building 'qtdeclarative' was explicitly disabled.
Checking dependencies of 'qtscxml'
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:81 (message):
  Module 'qtscxml' depends on 'qtdeclarative', but building 'qtdeclarative'
  was explicitly disabled.

  Note: Use '-skip qtscxml' to exclude it from the build.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "C:/Qt/Static/src/qt-everywhere-src-6.2.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:947 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.


mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Qt\Static\6.2.3\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf'.
At C:\users\john\Desktop\qt_StaticBuid.ps1:167 char:6
+ "@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

These lines suggests that something is wrong with 'qtdeclarative' i.e.

```
Module 'qtscxml' depends on 'qtdeclarative', but building 'qtdeclarative'
was explicitly disabled.

Note: Use '-skip qtscxml' to exclude it from the build.
```

So I tried using `-skip qtscxml` option and it gives me others modules to keep skipping.

How to resolve this problem ?

I've not made changes in the script. just these two lines are edited to meet the `6.2.3` version

```
$QtSrcUrl = "https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.2/6.2.3/single/qt-everywhere-src-6.2.3.zip"
$QtVersion = "6.2.3", #If you change this, you'll need to change the URL above to download as well...
```

I'm using `QT Creator 5.0.2` along with `6.2.3 MinGW`